# How can I get a value of "" in a string array to be treated as "0"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I haven't been able to find a resolution to this issue and would really appreciate it if someone can see one.

I have a string array. Usually the string array will contain multiple string Ids, (e.g. "1", "2", "3"), but sometimes it will contain a single empty string, (i.e. a string with the value ""). (This cannot be changed because it's integral to the design of the system.)

The string Ids are then converted to integers, and stored within a list, but if the string Id is "", then the conversion doesn't work, because you can't convert an empty string to an integer, because it doesn't have a numeric equivalent.

I am trying to use the Replace method, to replace empty strings with "0", which would then convert fine to 0, but the Replace method won't replace instances of "" because I am essentially saying, replace instances of nothing, which doesn't make sense.

```
foreach (string stringId in stringArray)
{
    intList.Add(Convert.ToInt32(stringId.Replace("", "0")));
}
```

So my question is, how can I get an instance of "" in a string array to be either treated as, or converted to "0"?

Answer (score 2):

Using the technique you have above, you just need to include a conditional check:

```
foreach (string stringId in stringArray)
{
    intList.Add(Convert.ToInt32((stringId == "" ? "0" : stringId)));
}
```

---

You could also use ConvertAll for a single line implementation:

```
intList = Array.ConvertAll(stringArray, s => (s == "" ? 0 : int.Parse(s))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Break it into multiple statements:

```
foreach (string stringId in stringArray)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringId)) {
         intList.Add(Convert.ToInt32(stringId));
    }
    else {
      intList.Add(0);
    }
}
```

or use `int.TryParse`.

```
foreach (string stringId in stringArray)
{
    int id;
    int.TryParse(stringId, out id);
    intList.Add(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ:

```
 intList = stringArray.Select(str => String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? 0 : Int32.Parse(str))
                      .ToList();
```

or [`Array.ConvertAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53(v=vs.110).aspx) with the same delegate:

```
intList = Array.ConvertAll(stringArray, str => String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? 0 : Int32.Parse(str))
               .ToList();
```